# Is calling MemoryStream.ToArray() dangerous after disposing?

Tags: c#, stream

In the below code, is there any chance the GC will clean out the MemoryStream so that ToArray will fail, since it is outside the using statement?

```
private static byte[] getBytes()
{
    MemoryStream ms = null;

    using (ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // ...
    }

    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, there's no chance of that. It's safe to do - the `MemoryStream` keeps a strong reference to the byte array.

I'll see if I can find any documentation about guarantees...

EDIT: Sort of...

From [`MemoryStream.Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342994(v=VS.90).aspx):

> The buffer is still available on a `MemoryStream` once the stream has been closed.

Admittedly that doesn't guarantee it for `Dispose`, but that's documented to call `Stream.Close`.

`MemoryStream.Dispose(bool)` *could* then be overridden to release the array, but it doesn't in my experience, and it would be a breaking change at this point.

Comment: I didn't find anything in the docs, but we have tests in Mono for this and the code works in this case. Btw, no need to call ms.Close().

Comment: Just a note: The .NET 4.0 documentation for MemoryStream.Close (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.close%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) *does not* contain the "The buffer is still available on a MemoryStream once the stream has been closed." statement. Makes me wonder if they did wind up changing behavior.

Comment: @scottmarlowe: That's the documentation for Stream.Close. It looks like they've just stopped providing "overriding documentation" for MemoryStream.Close. Changing the actual behaviour would have broken a lot of code.

Comment: OK, I see. They did away with the doc page for .NET 4.0 MemoryStream.Close in favor of Stream.Close. Thanks for pointing that out. I suppose as long as the MemoryStream object remains in-scope the underlying buffer is safe to access via ToArray even after the MemoryStream has been closed? That's what I'm getting from the code anyway.

Comment: @scottmarlowe: Yes. Basically, Close/Dispose don't do anything to the buffer. They could have chosen differently for v1.0, but it's way too late to change that now.

Comment: The documentation for the `ToArray` function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx) states that "This method works when the MemoryStream is closed."

Comment: @JonSkeet: If you look at the [MemoryStream reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs#1a4dcb744a23ba6f), you'll see there is no implementation of Close on the `MemoryStream`, which I suspect is the reason there's no overriding documentation. The docs for [MemoryStream.GetBuffer()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer(v=vs.110).aspx) note that  the method '...works when the memory stream is closed'.