# Aliases in using block in C#

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I have a question about the following code:

```
DisposableObject holdon = null;

using (DisposableObject o = new DisposableObject())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Inside using block");
    holdon = o;
}

holdon.Method();
```

When I ran this code, I expected to get an exception on the line `holdon.Method()`, but to my surprise, It happily called `Method()` without any problem. I was able to confirm that `DisposableObject.Dispose()` is being called on `o` upon hitting the end of the using block. This raises a question that I didn't have a lot of luck finding the answer to on MSDN. After the using block, `holdon` is definitely still pointing to a valid object in memory despite the fact that `Dispose()` was called. So does `holdon` still point to the same object previously pointed to by `o`, or does it point to a copy of `o`?

Answer (score 9):

Disposing object is not related to removing object from memory. It only means calling `Dispose()` method on that object. All further actions depend on `IDisposable` implementation of the object you have disposed. In some cases object is set to 'disposed' state and all further actions raise an exception (`ObjectDisposedException`). But you are free to do anything (or not do) when you implement `IDisposable`.

E.g. this is a totally valid `IDisposable` implementation ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DAnuZN)):

```
public class CrazyDisposable : IDisposable
{
    public int Counter { get; private set; }
    public void Dispose() => Counter++;
}
```

---

Further reading: [using statement (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

And particularly part which explains why it's better to limit the scope of the disposable object to the `using` block:

> You can instantiate the resource object and then pass the variable to
>   the using statement, but this is not a best practice. In this case,
>   the object remains in scope after control leaves the using block even
>   though it will probably no longer have access to its unmanaged
>   resources. In other words, it will no longer be fully initialized. If
>   you try to use the object outside the using block, *you risk causing an
>   exception to be thrown*. For this reason, it is generally better to
>   instantiate the object in the using statement and limit its scope to
>   the using block.

as you can see - it's allowed, but you ***risk*** when you access the disposed object.

Comment: In particular it is very common pattern for `MemoryStream` - dispose and than `ToArray` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981253/is-calling-memorystream-toarray-dangerous-after-disposing. Most operations like `Read` on `MemoryStream` will throw after disposing but `ToArray` will work as one would expect it too.

Comment: Alexei Levankov, what about open database connections, particularly an ODAC OracleConnection? The reason I ran in to this in the first place is because I am investigating a resource leak involving `OracleConnection` objects and a maxed out connection pool. The live code is instantiating the connections inside using blocks, but the connections are not being released back to the pool in some cases.

Comment: I would trust that the `using` construct is working as expected, so it is likely that either 1) there is a bug in the connection pool, or 2) there are other connections being created that are not properly closed (i.e. not wrapped in a using block).  Although the using blocks may not be the problem, you could write your own try-finally-dispose implementations (just like Scott's answer) to replace the using along with appropriate trace calls to log precisely what connections are being created and disposed, etc.

Answer (score 2):

the `using` statement is just shorthand for

```
DisposableObject holdon = null;

{ //This "{" is here to limit the scope of "o"

    DisposableObject o = new DisposableObject()
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside using block");
        holdon = o;
    }
    finally
    {
        if(o != null)
        o.Dispose();
    }

}

holdon.Method();
```

So if calling

```
o.Dispose();
o.Method();
```

in normal code does not cause a exception then calling `holdon.Method()` after `o.Dispose()` will not cause a exception either.

Comment: Showing how `using` is actually implemented is a great addition to this question. It allows someone to realise exactly how the framework deals with it. Great post!